# What is the opentelemetry equivalent for MockTracer

Tags: java, mocking, opentracing, open-telemetry

I am trying to migrate a java project written with opentracing into opentelemetry. While there are equivalent classes provided for main functionality, there are no mock classes provided by opentelemetry. How do we write tests with opentelemetry? Do we have to write our own `MockTracer`, `MockSpan` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the real tracer and span classes but export the data to an inMemorySpanExporter. You can then check the exporter contains the tracer/span data you would expect, this is for javascript but there must be a java equivalent:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/main/packages/opentelemetry-tracing/test/export/InMemorySpanExporter.test.ts